# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused laravel 5.4

Tags: database-connection, laravel-5.4, linux-mint

I have created a dashboard using laravel 5.4 and its worked well before.but now when i tried to login dashboard i got an error like

> ErrorException in Connection.php line 647:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from
>   `settings` where `key` = title limit 1) (View:
>   /var/www/html/testadmin/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/login.blade.php)

also i ran `php artisan migrate` i got

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from
>   information_s     chema.tables where table_schema = admin and
>   table_name = migrations)
>
> ```
>                                             [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]           SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> ```
>
> Connection refused
>
> ```
>                                             [PDOException]                                SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
> ```

my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=admin   
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

then i have change  DB_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to localhost(.env) but still the same issue.it worked before.Please help me.

Comment: Please check your DB_PORT in .env

Comment: @PankitGami-its 3306

Answer (score 4):

This error means your database configurations are wrong. Please check your database configuration. 
Try following steps :

1) run the following command : `php artisan config:clear`

2) Check whether the default port is 3306 or anything else. Check the process name and port

```
netstat -tln
```

3) Here I assume you are using Ubuntu. Have a look in `/etc/hosts` as well to ensure everything is fine there

Comment: -tcp        0      0 192.168.10.118:3306     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                           i got this when i ran netstat -tln

Comment: Was there any entry with `127.0.0.1:3306` or  `0.0.0.0:3306`?

Comment: got tcp        0      0 192.168.10.118:3306     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  this only

Comment: Change your `DB_HOST` to `192.168.10.118`

Comment: -SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '192.168.10.118' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: Am late to the party, however I will echo pankit, check your db connections settings. In my case, my php docker was trying to connect to my mysql docker using 127.0.0.1:33006, which is the host & port mysql docker was exposing, this is obviously not correct.

Comment: if db config is ok, command `php artisan config:clear` solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

After long hours this worked for me:

Changing the port in php My Admin previously 8889

```
 APP_NAME=laravel
 APP_ENV=local
 APP_KEY= YOUR KEY
 APP_DEBUG=true
 APP_URL=127.0.0.1
 LOG_CHANNEL=stack
 
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and then

```
  php artisan cache:clear
  php artisan route:clear
  php artisan config:clear
  php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by running those cmds:

```
  php artisan cache:clear
  php artisan route:clear
  php artisan config:clear
  php artisan view:clear
```